# SASS how to ignore style in css file to be overwritten by sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a style in a sass file that is written like

```
.style{
  width: calc(100%);
}
```

However, for some reason the output to its corresponding css file is

```
.style{
  width: 100%;
}
```

And it removes the calc(), which is needed. I figure a solution to this would be for this to be put manually into the css file and have sass ignore it so it is not overwritten, but I am not sure as to how to ignore a style in sass

Answer (score 0):

calc is a function into which you insert a calculation.
According to your example you did not enter a calculation like
calc(100% - 70%)

Which would give a width of 30%, but specified the value you want

Comment: I am aware of that, but there are other factors that need that the css file has the calc()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your sass compiler removed the calc() for asset optimization because it is redondant in this context : `calc(100%)` === `width: 100%` 
Does this also happens when you do a actual calculation like `calc(100% - 30px)` ?
If so, i'd advice you to take a look at your sass compiler configuration.

By the way, which tool are you using for compiling sass ? (Webpack ? parcel ? rollup ?...)